# Some questions about the factorization of an ideal and its extension in a ring of integers.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K\subset L$ be two number fields and let $I,J\subset \mathcal{O}_K,$ two ideals. I know that the ring of integers of a field is a Dedekind domain, and so I have the unique factorization in prime ideale for its ideals. My questions are: how are related the factorizations of $I$ in $ \mathcal{O}_K,$ and $I\mathcal{O}_L,$ in $\mathcal{O}_L?$ If $I\mathcal{O}_L,$ lies over 
$J\mathcal{O}_L,$ how can I prove that $I$ lies over $J?$ I can factor them in $\mathcal{O}_K,$ say
$$I=P_1^{a_1}...P_r^{a_r}\quad J=Q_1^{b_1}...Q_s^{b_s}$$
I also know that the primes which figure out in the factorizations of the two ideal extensions are those who lie over the ideals.  Probably the answer is quite simple, but I'm stuck..

Comment: When you say that $I$ lies over $J$, do you mean that $I$ contains $J$? Can you clarify what exactly your question is - for example, are you asking how to prove that the factorisations are of the form you've written? Or are you asking what can be said about those factorisations for specific ideals?

Comment: When I say $I$ lies over $J$ I mean $I\supset J.$ I know that this is equivalent to a number of things, one of which is this one, as explained in Marcus book "Number fields" (page 63)

Comment: The fact is, I know that the primes which figure out in the factorisation of $I\mathcal{O}_L$ are the primes which lies over $I=P_1^{a_1}\dots P_r^{a_r}.$ I observe that for all $i,$ $P_i\supset I,$ so I think that the factorisation of $I\mathcal{O}_L$ is of the form $I=P_1^{A_1}\dots P_r^{A_r}R,$ where $A_i\geq a_i$ and $R$ is the product of other primes, if there are any. Is it right? Are there any other primes a part the $P_i?$

Comment: A key fact that you're missing is that in general, if $P\subset\mathcal O_K$ is prime, $P\mathcal O_L$ will not be prime (e.g. $5\mathbb Z[i]$ is not prime).

Comment: I have $P_i\mathcal{O}_L$ will factor with other primes. The factorisation of $I\mathcal{O}_L$ is the product of these factorisation, isn’t it? Is this the right way?